# postgresql 9.6.15

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to install PostgreSQL 9.5.15 but I get:

> Error 404 Not Found

Command:

```sh
rpm -Uvh https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/9.6/redhat/rhel-6-x86_64/pgdg-centos96-9.6-3.noarch.rpm;
```

I did install latest version in 9.6 (9.6.17) using yum. once i log in to my postgresql i got this error :

Erreur SQL :

ERROR: column "spclocation" does not exist LINE 1: ...pg_catalog.pg_get_userbyid(spcowner) AS spcowner, spclocatio... ^ Dans l'instruction :

SELECT spcname, pg_catalog.pg_get_userbyid(spcowner) AS spcowner, spclocation, (SELECT description FROM pg_catalog.pg_shdescription pd WHERE pg_tablespace.oid=pd.objoid) AS spccomment FROM pg_catalog.pg_tablespace WHERE spcname NOT LIKE $$pg_%$$ ORDER BY spcname

Comment: because the file is not there. isn't it obvious?

Comment: Yes i know but i was looking for this version about 2 days but i can't not find it

Comment: why do you need this version?

Comment: i have an app it only work with this version and cent os 6 :'(

Comment: version 9.6 or 9.5 ??

Comment: i need 9.6.15  !!

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/redhat/

Answer (score 0):

postgres 9.6 installation

```
yum install https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/reporpms/EL-6-x86_64/pgdg-redhat-repo-latest.noarch.rpm
```

or

```
yum install postgresql96
```

Comment: i got this error :

Erreur SQL :

ERROR: column "spclocation" does not exist LINE 1: ...pg_catalog.pg_get_userbyid(spcowner) AS spcowner, spclocatio...